# IntelliJ IDEA ignores CLASSPATH

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classpath

I have a class called Test01 in a directory that is in the CLASSPATH on my machine (running Windows 7). When I compile and run the code shown below using javac from the command line it works fine.

```
class LinkTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This line hard coded within main.");
        System.out.println(Test01.get());
    }
}
```

When I create a project consisting of the above code within IntelliJ IDEA it generates the error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'Test01'
```

This leads me to suspect that IntelliJ IDEA has no IDEA that there is such a thing as the CLASSPATH. If that is not the case, how can I get IntelliJ IDEA to use it?

Follow up:

From the responses it appears that ItelliJ IDEA (and perhaps other IDEs) does not use CLASSPATH. If I have a class that will potentially be shared among multiple projects, and it is located in a directory outside of any particular project's directory, what's the correct way to tell IntelliJ IDEA about it?

Comment: Show the structure of project in IntelliJ. Might be that you placed those files in different pacakges in the IDE?

Comment: You are correct in that assumption by the way, any IDE in existence builds its own classpath from the project structure. The CLASSPATH environmental variable only affects using the JDK command line tools directly.